# RecyclerView with CardView rows where each row has 1 or more TextViews stacked vertically all loaded from same cursor

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my application with each row in a `CardView` with the data loaded from the database using `Loader/cursor`. Just the basic `RecyclerView/CardView` stuff.
The data from the DB is structured like this:

`| _id   | main_id   | sub_id    | title         |
|-----  |---------  |--------   |-------------- |
| 1     | 1         | 1         | Main 1 Sub 1  |
| 2     | 1         | 2         | Main 1 sub 2  |
| 3     | 2         | 1         | Main 2 sub 1  |
| 4     | 3         | 1         | Main 3 sub 1  |
| 5     | 3         | 2         | Main 3 sub 2  |
| 6     | 3         | 3         | Main 3 sub 3  |`

I have been able to display `DISTINT` `main_id`'s and `title` for each record in the `RecyclerView/CardView`. Like Below 
[image]

### The Question proper:

I Want to display it like this: 
[image]

Is it possible with the same Cursor? 
I have a Custom RecyclerView adapter with a View holder. Please how do i go about it.Thanks